# unable to execute RecieveEvent() and RegisterEventProcessorAsync inside web application failed to use azure event hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-eventhub

Console application works perfect with `Azure Event Hub` but When I try to put 
`RecieveEvent()` code inside `Index.aspx.cs` it gets a call but after this it failed to execute

```
  eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(options).Wait(); and `SimpleEventProcessor.cs` code why so ?
```

How to do it in web application?

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
[WebMethod]

        public static void RecieveEvent()
        {
            string eventHubConnectionString = "Endpoint=sb://rpidemoeventhub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=wyi1HpKwEIOpiSPnQaCloPr9ELhESOSD/F2SJiY0RFU=";
            string eventHubName = "myeventhubname";
            string storageAccountName = "mystoragename";
            string storageAccountKey = "mykey";
            string storageConnectionString = string.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}", storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

            string eventProcessorHostName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            EventProcessorHost eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(eventProcessorHostName, eventHubName, EventHubConsumerGroup.DefaultGroupName, eventHubConnectionString, storageConnectionString);
            //Console.WriteLine("Registering EventProcessor...");
            var options = new EventProcessorOptions();
            options.ExceptionReceived += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Exception); };
            eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<SimpleEventProcessor>(options).Wait();

            //Console.WriteLine("Receiving. Press enter key to stop worker.");
            //Console.ReadLine();
            eventProcessorHost.UnregisterEventProcessorAsync().Wait();
        }
```

**SimpleEventProcessor**

```
public class SimpleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
    {
        Stopwatch checkpointStopWatch;

        async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Processor Shutting Down. Partition '{0}', Reason: '{1}'.", context.Lease.PartitionId, reason);
            if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown)
            {
                await context.CheckpointAsync();
            }
        }

        Task IEventProcessor.OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("SimpleEventProcessor initialized.  Partition: '{0}', Offset: '{1}'", context.Lease.PartitionId, context.Lease.Offset);
            this.checkpointStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            this.checkpointStopWatch.Start();
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        async Task IEventProcessor.ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
        {
            foreach (EventData eventData in messages)
            {
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

                //TODO: sed mail notification

                if (Convert.ToInt32(data) > 25 && Index.isMail == false)
                {
                    SendMail();
                    Index.isMail = true;
                }
                //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message received.  Partition: '{0}', Data: '{1}'",
                //    context.Lease.PartitionId, data));
            }

            //Call checkpoint every 5 minutes, so that worker can resume processing from 5 minutes back if it restarts.
            if (this.checkpointStopWatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
            {
                await context.CheckpointAsync();
                this.checkpointStopWatch.Restart();
            }
        }
```

Unable to execute this above call , call does not comes here why? 
Instead of using any worker role or webjob can it work?

Comment: You are calling `RegisterEventProcessorAsync` followed immediately by `UnregisterEventProcessorAsync` - the `IEventProcessor` probably doesn't have enough time to act on anything, and even if it did, you really have no control here of how many EventHub messages get picked up. If you remove `UnregisterEventProcessorAsync`, I'm guessing things work, but the processor incorrectly continues to receive messages? I think you're going to have to put some thought into how you design this.

Comment: why not use a web job?

Comment: no specific reason to not to use web job or worker role , I just want to know it works with any web app or not

Comment: @pep nope i tried that as well it is not working , i guess it will not work with web app should be deployed separately as worker / web job

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it would not work with a web app, I suspect you'd have this same problem in a worker role, though I'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to p e p's first comment that explains why it does not work consider this:

You should see the purpose of an `EventProcessor` to read the incoming stream of events to the `EventHub` in a continuous process / loop (The `ProcessEventsAsync` method is called while the `EventProcessor` instance is up and running. That's why a web job / worker role is better suited for this than doing this in a web app page since that is meant to handle a request in a reasonable amount of time.

If you really want it to run in a web app page, do not use an `EventProcessor` but create a direct receiver (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-programming-guide/#event-consumers) and specify an amount of messsage you want to receive using the `Receive(In32)` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790451.aspx. That way you can process and display a finite amount of messages.

I don't know your specific use case but we host the `EventProcessor` in a web job that runs continuously and when the web job shuts down due to a stop command or something we can gracefully stop the `EventProcessor` by calling `UnregisterEventProcessorAsync()`.

Comment: perfect explanation for understanding thanks a lot , yes we have used a worker role but i just wonder how it works with web app , thanks :)